# ASP .NET chart disappears when click in link

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

First of all I am complete beginner(especially with ASP .NET) so it could be even difficult to explain my problem in a clear way.

My idea is to save dynamically generated ASP .NET chart.

On a single page I have:

- a few controls (two calendars and group box) which sets parameters of my chart ,
- panel with Chart control inside
- two link buttons: "GENERATE" generates chart, "SAVE" should save generated chart into file.

Pretty easy isn't it ?

I have no problems with generate chart - it works. The problem is when I fire LinkSave_Click event.

```
protected void LinkSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "c:\\temp\\";
        string nameoffile = "TEST";
        string data = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy_HHmmss");
        string tekst = path + @"\" + nameoffile + "_" + data + ".png";
        Chart2.Width = 1800;
        Chart2.Height = 1100;
        Chart2.SaveImage(tekst, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Page_Load Event Below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (!IsPostBack)
   { 
        this.Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7); 
        this.Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; 
    } 
 }
```

I expect to save generated chart into file. But before it happens chart disappears.
so generated file is empty :(

Comment: Is the `Page_Load` event altering the chart at all?  That would effectively clobber it before this method has a chance to save it.

Comment: here is my Page_Load:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
                this.Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
            }
        }

Comment: Can you do some debugging and stop on any line that modifies or examines `Chart2` in any way?  Literally anything could be happening in other code on the page.  You'll want to narrow down specifically when/where `Chart2` loses its expected values.  Conversely, you'll want to identify where it *gets* its expected values and make sure it's also getting that on the post-back.

Comment: look at this line `string tekst = path + @"\" + nameoffile + "_" + data + ".png";` you do not need to `"@\"` change the original file path to 
`string path = @"c:\temp\"` for starters

Comment: when you debug your code and use the `QuickWatch` what is the value of `tekst` when you click the `Magnifying Glass` I get this when I run your code which is not correct `c:\temp\\TEST_25Nov2014_092340.png` your code should be the following `string path = @"c:\temp\";` then 
`string tekst = path + nameoffile + "_" + data + ".png";` it's amazing what you can see and or discover when you use the `Debugger`

Comment: some "new" (maybe) important info: 
- all my code is in fact inside content of MasterPage. 
- in the same time I also generate GridView . It contains the same data (from the same datatable) as in chart. It does not disappear.

About  debugging. First line of code is first line of LinkSave_Click. In that moment my Chart has already only one series with no points.

Comment: TEST_25nov2014_153805  - here is the name of the file. I have plenty of them in the temp directory. All have 10kb and all are empty :\
Anyway I changed string tekst as you suggested